# WebView não mostra menu flutuante do site

Tags: webview

**Abrindo site pelo Chrome:** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Abrindo pelo APP:** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que o menu flutuante aparece no Chrome mas não no WebView do APP.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço desde já :)

Comment: Como você está fazendo a requisição? Poderia postar o trecho de código responsável pelo request?

Comment: Estou apenas carregando a página, nada mais: 

`webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView );
webView.loadUrl("http://pn-coc.sitefacil.com/");`

Comment: Tente isso: http://rshankar.com/swift-webview-demo/

Comment: Parceiro, isso aí é desenvolvimento IOS. Não tem como isso me ajudar.

Comment: O meu camarada me perdoe, acabei me confundindo aqui.